# How to stop further routing in a plug?

Tags: authentication, routes, elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I'm using Phoenix, and in `router.ex`, I have defined a function that verifies the user's JWT token, before continuing on to routing through the api, in order to protect the routes. However, I am having the issue that if, say, I return a status of 403 in the plug, it continues routing and I end up getting an error as I am both accessing the route *and* disallowing access.

My code looks something like this:

```
def validate(conn, _opts) do
  if !Map.has_key?(conn.cookies, "jwt") do
    conn
    |> send_resp(403, "Forbidden")
    # I would like to have something here that stops further
    # routing - i.e. a way to say 'already sent a response; don't keep going'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from [`Plug.Conn.send_resp/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_resp/3)

> Note that this function does not halt the connection, so if subsequent plugs try to send another response, it will error out. Use [`halt/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#halt/1) after this function if you want to halt the plug pipeline.